# ASP.NET Identity code convert from C# to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-identity

Please Refer below Code snippest,

```
   public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and role manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);   .................
```

This above code snippest is found into Startup.cs file in my default MVC template.

I want to convert project into VB.NET.  But I have issue to converting above four lines into VB.NET

Please let me know what is the sutaible syntax to convert this above lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`AddressOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b.aspx)

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(AddressOf ApplicationDbContext.Create)
app.CreatePerOwinContext(Of ApplicationUserManager)(AddressOf ApplicationUserManager.Create)
app.CreatePerOwinContext(Of ApplicationRoleManager)(AddressOf ApplicationRoleManager.Create)
app.CreatePerOwinContext(Of ApplicationSignInManager)(AddressOf ApplicationSignInManager.Create)
```

Comment: That is quite useful. Thanks!